# appendChild not working on some elements

Tags: javascript, html, forms, appendchild

I'm working on a vanilla javascript project so I cannot use jQuery. I'm trying to use the following to move some HTML from one placement to another:

```
parent.appendChild(element);
```

I'm trying to place the forms into a different placement as I placed in the comment in my HTML code. I'm trying this but it's not working at all.

Javascript:

```
var loginButton = document.querySelector('[data-login-header-button]');
var loginDropdown = document.querySelector('[data-login-dropdown]');

var shopCartButton = document.querySelector('[data-shopping-cart-header-button]');
var shopCartDropdown = document.querySelector('[data-shopping-header-cart]');

shopCartButton.parentNode.appendChild(shopCartDropdown);
loginButton.parentNode.appendChild(loginDropdown);
```

HTML:

```
<header>
    <nav data-nav-services>
        <ul class="nav-services">
            <li data-test>
                <a class="icon icon-shopping-cart icon-arrow-down" href="#" data-shopping-cart-header-button>
                    shopping cart
                </a>
                <!-- PLACEMENT FOR data-shopping-header-cart -->
            </li>
            <li>
                <a class="icon icon-user icon-arrow-down" href="#" data-login-header-button>
                    Login
                </a>
                <!-- PLACEMENT FOR data-login-dropdown -->
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>

    <form class="login-dropdown" data-login-dropdown>
        ...CONTENT...
    </form>

    <form class="shopping-cart" data-shopping-header-cart>
        ..CONTENT..
    </form>
</header>
```

The strange thing is that if I turn around the selectors (as here below) it does work and I cannot explain why...

```
shopCartDropdown.parentNode.appendChild(shopCartButton);
shopCartDropdown.parentNode.appendChild(loginButton);
```

Comment: Your original code works for me. http://jsfiddle.net/8mB3h/

Comment: @Arbel I really do not understand why, but the fiddle is the logic outcome and that is exactly what I need but on my code it only works turning around the selectors. Really strange... if I find out something I will let you know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anybody who wish to know, the code was perfect. The issue was that I was appending this form elsewhere of my code. So there was a conflict as one had a priority over the other. I could use `.cloneNode(true)` as a solution. I ended transforming that appending to my new goal and solved the issue.

Anybody out there... check all the code for any other appending of the same element. Good advice ;)

Answer (score 0):

When you do:

```
shopCartButton.parentNode.appendChild(shopCartDropdown);
loginButton.parentNode.appendChild(loginDropdown);
```

It actually works. It is just not showing anything since the forms are empty. Check your Dev Tools and inspect your HTML.